How to modify an environment variable from a MakeFile generated by a CMakeLists.txt?
I'm building a Qt project using CMake under Linux.
My CMakeLists.txt generates .make files that I later run with make command. Because the projet contains .ui files, at some point uic is invoked. However, because the uic tool was compiled on a different machine, some .so files are missing and uic won't start. I have those .so files in a folder and I just want to help uic tool finding them.
If I modify the .make file and add:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=:/3rdparty/tools_ext/lib/lin64

Now uic works just fine.
However, I'm not supposed to modify my .make file as it is regenerated everytime I run CMake. Is there any way to have this modification of LD_LIBRARY_PATH be added to .make file by CMake itself (by adding some extra lines to my CMakeLIsts.txt?
I'd like to avoid having to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH is my whole system environment (~/.cshrc)...


Is there any way to have this modification of LD_LIBRARY_PATH be added to .make file by CMake itself (by adding some extra lines to my CMakeLIsts.txt?

Not as far as I am aware, but there are alternatives.
In the first place, I really don't understand why you are satisfied to be stuck with a broken Qt development environment.  And it is broken if you have to supplement it with additional shared libraries that are not bundled with it.  The best solution would be to fix your build environment.
But if you're unwilling or unable to fix the build environment, there are multiple ways to set environment variables within restricted scopes.  Your reference to ~/.cshrc suggests that you are using (t)csh as your login shell, which is unfortunate, but not fatal.  In this case, I would recommend writing a make wrapper that handles any environment-variable customization you need.  Something like this, for example:
my_make
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:}/3rdparty/tools_ext/lib/lin64
exec make "$@"

Put that somewhere in your path, and use it instead of using make directly.
The make process and all processes that inherit environment from it, such as those executing commands in make recipes, will see that environment variable unless something actively intervenes to prevent it.  Nothing else will see it, however, because each process has its own environment variables.  A child process cannot modify its parent's environment variables.
